# How do we add arbitrary number of ProgressBars given an input in Android?

Tags: java, android

If we receive an input number from EditText. How do we create that many number of ProgressBars? For example, if the input is 5. 5 progressBar widgets should be created.

Comment: you could create linear layout and add the number you want to it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Progress bar array.
final ProgressBar[] bars = new ProgressBar[numTAs+1];

//Create and initialize the Progress Bar array.
for(int i = 0; i < numTAs + 1; i++){
   //ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar(this);
   int style = android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Horizontal;
   ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
   bars[i] = bar;
}

//Build Adapter
ArrayAdapter<ProgressBar> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ProgressBar>(this, R.layout.layout, bars ){

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

                return bars[position];
            }
        };

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Comment: Please add some description about your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. In your **activity_main.xml** add linearLayout inside scrollView

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
</ScrollView>
```

2. In **MainActivity.java** add this code to add the progressBar to the linearLayout

   ```
   int wantedNumber = 5; //get that number from the editText.
   for (int i = 0; i < wantedNumber; i++) {
       ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar(this);
       bar.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
       LinearLayout linearLayout;
       linearLayout.addView(bar);
   }
   ```

I only mentioned the important parts let me know if you faced any problem.